# How to add third party dll with VS code in Ubuntu/Linux Enviroment?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have C# source code working in Windows **Visual Studio Code** (with integrated 3rd party dll). Will I be able to achieve the same with windows C# code in Ubuntu/Linux environment?(3rd party dll/.so file is available for linux as well)

Also, I have done a build in VS code for Ubuntu runtime and was able to generate **.so** files. Can I directly make use of them for run on Ubuntu environment.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You really need to describe further what exactly you would like to do. Microsoft does have things like `dotnet add package` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package to add references.

Comment: I would like to run C# program with VS code in ubuntu . I am using a third party dll in my C# program. Please suggest how to go ahead with ubuntu/linux using VS code.

Comment: the simplest way is to manually add a reference by editing the project file. You can learn the MSBuild syntax from existing projects on GitHub.

Comment: @Lex Li: Thanks a lot for your response. I have another related question.Can I just build and run a C# program with Visual Studio CODE in linux/ubuntu environment with only third party dlls(not using any .so files).